# MySQL Conditional Left Join With Default

Tags: mysql, left-join, conditional-statements

Is there a way to make a conditional `left join`, which will `left join` on a default value if a match is not found?

I have a `client` table and a `preference` table. Record 0 in the `preference` table is my global default preference. There are cases in which a client may override of the global reference, in which case the client would have its own record in the `preference` table.

So, I'm looking to do a `left join` of the preference table on `client.ClientID = preference.ClientID` however if there is no match, then I want to left join `preference.ClientID = 0` instead.

Comment: you need to restrict if you have `clientID <> 0 ` then only select this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [SqlFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a856b/6/0)

```
select * from client, preference
where preference.clientID in (select MAX(preference.ClientID)
                              from preference 
                              where preference.ClientID = client.ClientID OR preference.ClientID = 0)
```

or

```
select client.name, MAX(preference.ClientID)
from client
left join preference on preference.ClientID = client.ClientID OR preference.ClientID = 0
group by client.name
```

Comment: Sort of, if I have an override for ClientID 8 then I get two results back for them. One with the match and one with the default value. I need just the one result with the override in this case.

Comment: I think it still needs some work. I would recommend removing your 1st query as it gives dups. I think the 2nd one would work for one specific ClientID, but you need to add that in a `where`. I'd like to see this work for a all clients through. I need to give some thought to your 3rd query.

Comment: @VenomFangs Oh I got it

Comment: @VenomFangs Updated again

Comment: The third query you had before this last update worked. As it did the `Max()` with the `group by` and together it gives the desired results. I'll have to look at this new post, to see if it works as well.

Comment: @VenomFangs The third query worked, but you need to put all the fields on group by